# When did the defined function start returning false for arrays that have not held any items

Tags: perl

In which release did the `defined` function start returning false for arrays that have not held any items (or have had `undef` called on them)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how it works on Perl 4 (I found some docs and interpreters for 4.036 [here](http://www.burtonsys.com/auxil/)).

And that's how it appears to be in the [documentation for Perl 3.044](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/perl-3.044/perl.man.2) 
(update: and [Perl 3.000](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/perl-3.000/perl.man.2)).

As the `defined` keyword does not appear to be part of the language in version 2 (man pages [here](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/perl-2.001/perl.man.1) and [here](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/perl-2.001/perl.man.2)), it looks like the answer to your question is Perl 3.000.

If I get any of these older versions built and running, I'll confirm.

Comment: The docs are helpful.  They lend weight to the argument that `defined` is and has been seriously broken.